# How to perform in laravel multiple where with or query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

```
Product::where('name', 'like', 'something%')->orWhere('category', 'like', 'something%')->orWhere('price', 'like', 'something%')->orWhere('qty', 'like', 'something%')...
```

Can I do it in more elegant and compact way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `searchable`, take a look [here](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) and [here](https://github.com/jedrzej/searchable) also [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout)

Answer (score 1):

You can go about it this way. passing arrays to a single `orWhere` clause

`Product::where('name', 'like', 'something%')->orWhere(['category', 'like', 'something%'], ['price', 'like', 'something%'],['qty', 'like', 'something%'])...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['array_map()'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to build an array for `orWhere()`:

```
$search = 'something';
Product::orWhere(array_map(
    function ($i) use($search) { return [$i, 'like', $search.'%']; },
    ['name', 'category', 'price', 'qty']
))->get();
```

It's a good way if you have many fields to search by. For 3-4 fields, I'd just use simple `orWhere()` chaining, because it's easier to read the code